# How Can I Check The Date Submitted is Between Two Dates in Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which has a table called dates. In this table there is start_date and end_date, both types are date. Let's say for example in the table there is a start_date of 2018-01-25 and an end_date of 2018-01-31. How can I stop someone else submitting my form with a date in between the two.

Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="dates.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

    <label>Start Date *</label>
    <input name="startDate" id="startDate" type="date" required>
    <label>End Date *</label>
    <input name="endDate" id="endDate" type="date" required>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

Once the form has been submitted the dates are placed in the table in the same format as I mentioned earlier.

In dates.php I get the startDate and endDate like so:

```
$start = $_REQUEST['startDate'];
$end = $_REQUEST['endDate'];
```

I then try and add some form of validation:

```
    $sql = " SELECT * FROM dates WHERE start_date = '$start' AND end_date = '$end'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($row_cnt > 0) {
            $isBooked = true;
        } else {
            $isBooked = false;
        }
```

I then have a function so that if isRepeat = true it redirects to an error page instead of submitting duplicate data.

I have a feeling the validation bit is the part of code which is broken but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Put the check directly in your query and then just check to see if any rows are returned. It's far less complicated than this.

Comment: @JohnConde do you mean in the $sql = "SELECT * FROM dates"; bit? How could I do that if so?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @TheWelshManc did it work?

Comment: @Andam I edited your code a little bit, so I gave you a correct answer because it was the closest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `where` clause in your sql query. It will filter the selected rows based on conditions. You can specify your start and end date there. The query for it, is something like that.

the `AND` in the `start_date = yourStartDate AND  end_date = yourEndData` mean if both conditions are true then select the row otherwise don't select it..'

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE start_date = yourStartDate AND  end_date = yourEndData
```

**Note:** you dont need to validation  (the if statement) anymore just check if the query returned any rows like below.

```
$isRepeat = (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0);
```

Comment: You should expand upon your answer as this really doesn't explain *how* this solves their problem

Comment: @JohnConde I agree, I will

Comment: Where would the validation be? How would it stop other uses submitting the form with dates in between start and end?

Comment: @TheWelshManc I have updated the answer to explain it more

Comment: @TheWelshManc I have added the check statment too

Comment: Wouldn't this only return any results if the start date and end date are the same? If the start date was 2 days after but end date was the same this would be false, right?

Comment: @TheWelshManc I will add this to the answer too. wait

Comment: I just tested putting in 2018-01-27 as the start date and 2018-01-29 as the end date but it still said there were no previous results and so it still was submitted

Comment: @TheWelshManc is this how you did it " SELECT * FROM dates  WHERE start_date = '$start' AND end_date = '$end '

Comment: Yes, with and without ' '

Comment: are you sure you have these start and end dates in your table @TheWelshManc

Comment: Like I said I have 2018-01-25 as the start date and 2018-01-31 in the table, if I try and add any date in between those two dates such as start date as 2018-01-27 and end date as 2018-01-30 it still adds which I don't want.

Comment: @TheWelshManc Put the php code after you have edited it

Comment: @TheWelshManc I have checked it mysefl its working https://imgur.com/a/DnJyo . Try using the query in the phpMyAdmin directly. See if it works there

Comment: Whatever the answer to this problem turns out to be, it isn't this :-(