# How To Make An Availability Calendar?

Tags: php, sql, calendar

This topic is slightly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431695/how-can-i-check-the-date-submitted-is-between-two-dates-in-database) so **PLEASE READ FIRST**.

Basically now I have it so dates can be booked and I can display them on a separate page like so:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dates";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<body>
<h2>Current Dates Booked:</h2>
<?php
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <p><?php 
    echo date("l jS F", strtotime(htmlspecialchars($rows['start_date'])))
        ." - "
        .date("l jS F", strtotime(htmlspecialchars($rows['end_date']))); 
        ?>
    </p><br>
    <?php
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
```

However I want to display them on a calendar like [this](http://www.dateblocker.com/AvailabilityCalendar?PropertyId=33932). Not necessarily having the same CSS with the red boxes and what not, but being able to have a calendar that updates to show what dates have already been inputted into the table to make it more user friendly and easier to read than scrolling through tons of dates printed on a screen.

However I am not sure where to start on making the calendar.

**EDIT:** I was able to add dates on the calendar using [this](https://codepen.io/peanav/pen/ulkof) method but I want to be able to block out all dates in between the two.

I have a live version of it [here](https://ryan-simms.com/booking/bookings.php) but not sure how to block out all dates in between